# Can Multiprocessor CPUs avoid context-switching?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Today's computer architecture are trying to maximize the number of registers. It is faster to access a register (which is an integrated memory circuit near the cpu) than to access first-level cache. The problem is, that each context switch has to save all registers into cache, because the next thread needs other register values. What a modern CPU is doing is to cycle in one second through 100 tasks and everytime it saves the registers, and fetches the old one until the task can be started.

IMHO it would be nice to use one CPU for one task, and no context switching is happening. That means we get 100 CPUs, each 1000 registers which has to be never saved. Is that possible or have I a ignored an important detail?

Comment: Probably you would be better off at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ with that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to completely avoid context switching is by having at least as many cores as there are tasks. Generally, there is no guarantee regarding the maximum number of tasks that may run. Current GPUs and manycore processors and co-processors contain hundreds of small cores. If you put multiple of these things in the same system or in a cluster of systems, you can have thousands or more cores. Still, even if you could avoid context switching with such design, these cores are much slower than the traditional high-end CPU cores, so the net effect might be negative.

But let's take a step back here. The number of context switches is not primarily determined by the number of tasks and cores. Tasks don't just perform computations, they also need to interact with I/O devices and wait for things to happen such as results from other tasks or user input. So some tasks would be in a wait state. The overhead of context switching depends on not only the number of tasks but also the behavior of these tasks.

Both processors architects and OS developers are aware of context switching overhead and employ a variety of techniques to alleviate it. For example, x86 provides a number of instructions that are tuned to saving the context (partially) of the current task. The OS thread scheduler uses techniques such as priorities, preemption (with possibly large time slices on servers), and priority boosting. All of these help reducing the number of context switches and therefore their overall overhead. In addition, reducing the overhead of context switching is not the only thing that matters. In particular, the responsiveness of the system is very important as well, which is at odds with that overhead.